# How to use getElementId for tag in an asp:Repeater

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have a div inside an asp:Repeater:

```
   <ItemTemplate>
          <div id="myDiv" style="display:none" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
          document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

This works great except my div elements occur within a repeater which means only the first div is found. Could some please explain to me how to get all the divs in the ItemTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is invalid to use the same id more than once on a page.  Instead you'll have to use some other means of finding your elements, such as css class.  jQuery makes this task easy.

```
$(".someClass").show();
```

However, you may not even need to do that.  If all you are trying to do is change some styles on a set of elements under a common parent, you can just change the class name of the parent.  Consider the following repeater:

```
<div id="repeaterParent">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="repeaterItemDiv"></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Set up your css like this:

```
#repeaterParent .repeaterItemDiv
{
    display: none;
}
#repeaterParent.showDivs .repeaterItemDiv
{
    display: block;
}
```

Then use this JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("repeaterParent").className = "showDivs";
```

Or, this jQuery:

```
$("#repeaterItemParent").addClass("showDivs");
```

Comment: Thanks gilly3. Easily best answer and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID value on the page. Use classes instead:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="myDiv" style="display:none" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Selecting the DIVs:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')
// or
document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv')
// or 
$('.myDiv') // jQuery
```

Comment: Yeah, but how am I going to get the elements in the javascript?

Comment: @Coder I recommend a library for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in javascript, you can do something like the following:

```
<div id="repeaterParent">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="myDiv" style="display:none" runat="server"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
          //get the parent element
          var ParentEle=document.getElementById('repeaterParent');
          //get all the div tags within parent element
          var AllDivInParentEle=ParentEle.getElementsByTagname('DIV');
          //loop div elements and do what is required
          for(var i=AllDivInParentEle.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            AllDivInParentEle[i].style.display = 'block';
          }
   }
</script>
```

Using runat="server" for the div will give it its own id.
But if the div does not need to have an id, the javascript method will still work as it relies on the parent elements id.

So you could replace

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none" runat="server"/>
```

with

```
<div style="display:none">
```